# Qt Android app example looks weird on real device

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to run the Qt example "Qt Quick Controls 2 - Gallery", and I can run it successfully on my Nexus 5X with Android 7, but the app doesn't look like it should. The first problem is that there are white lines at the screen edges, the second one is that the status bar is black, and I guess it should have the accent color of the app. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm using Qt 5.8

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWbgg.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBNMN.png)

Answer (score 0):

for the white line: I already opened a bug here:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53247

and for the statusbar color JP Nurmi provided a way to set the color: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51196

see also discussion in forum: 
https://forum.qt.io/topic/76541/android-applicationwindow-doesn-t-run-fullscreen